# Swagger is not Working Asp.net Core how to open swagger ui

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

This is my `Startup.cs` file

This is my `ConfigureService` method in Startup.cs. I have modified it exactly according to documentation, but it's not working. I have removed the launch Url, so it's just going on the port and I have not set any routing.

```cs
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.ConnectionToACQEs(Configuration);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "ToDo API",
                    Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API",
                    TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
                    Contact = new OpenApiContact
                    {
                        Name = "Nicky Liu",
                        Email = "nicky@zedotech.com",
                        Url = new Uri("https://www.zedotech.com"),
                    },
                    License = new OpenApiLicense
                    {
                        Name = "Use under LICX",
                        Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license"),
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

This is my `Configure` method:

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
       {
           //if (env.IsDevelopment())
           //{
           //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           //}


           /// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
           app.UseSwagger();
           // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
           // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
           app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
           {
               c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
           });
           //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

           app.UseRouting();

           //app.UseAuthorization();

           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
           {
               endpoints.MapControllers();
           });



       }
```

Comment: "its not working"... what indicates that this is the case?

Comment: spender The application is working fine one

localhost/Acquirer/Dashboard

i just want to go to swagger ui

Comment: Can you try with adding this 'c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;' in configure method to app.UseSwaggerUI. By this if you just load your domain (https://example.com) it will redirect to swagger ui

Comment: do you go to `https://localhost:yourport/swagger` or `http://localhost:yourport/swagger`? What do you see on that page?

Comment: https://localhost:44309/index.html

This was my url  @Julian

Comment: In `launchSettings.json`, set  `"launchUrl": "swagger"`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
 {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = "";
 });
```

[image]

Right click on your project and select Debug on your left panel and on your lauch broswer (absolute or relatve URL) just leave it empty.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, @Sydney_dev's answer did not work. It worked after removing `RoutePrefix` setting, but let me explain a little.

SwaggerUI is accessible at an URL similar to [https://localhost:5826/[RoutePrefix]](https://localhost:5826/%5BRoutePrefix%5D). When accessed, it returns a **permanent** redirect to the page where you can test the API. This permanent redirect is stored in the browser and has effect even if `RoutePrefix` is changed. This may end up redirecting and displaying an empty page with HTTP status 404 (Not Found).

In addition, when you start debugging your application the configuration next to the play button is used, for example UnifiedStockExchange is used in the picture bellow:

[image]

This configuration is searched in **Properties/launchSettings.json**. In my case, the following setting was specified:

```
"launchUrl": "swagger"
```

This means that when the application starts debugging it opens an URL similar to https://localhost:5826/swagger. When `RoutePrefix` is set to empty, SwaggerUI is not located there. Either change `launchUrl`, either remove `RoutePrefix` config (default is "swagger"), either change URL after launching the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning your build and building your project.

If it still doesn't work, make sure that your controller has no method without ActionVerbs, ie: `HttpGet, HttpPost` and so. Swagger requires all controller methods to have ActionVerbs, except those with `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` attribute.

None of your methods should define the route along with the ActionVerb:
Do `[HttpGet,Route("getuser")]` instead of `[HttpGet("getuser")]`