# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with Swagger not running as localhost web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I'm trying to created an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API using only CLI and have the `program.cs` as shown below.

When I run this from VS 2022, no compiler or runtime errors are appearing.

But when this is run from a "docker-compose up" I dot get specific error:

> 2024-03-28 17:54:11 Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' in the application startup code.
>
> 2024-03-28 17:54:11    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.VerifyServicesRegistered(IApplicationBuilder app)
> 2024-03-28 17:54:11    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.UseAuthorization(IApplicationBuilder app)
> 2024-03-28 17:54:11    at WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/Program.cs:line 41

Code:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            var services = builder.Services;

            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();

            services.AddControllers();

            /*
            Console.WriteLine("Preparing DbContext");
            services.AddDbContext<ParkingDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            */

            services.AddAuthorization(); // Move AddAuthorization here

            services.AddHealthChecks();

            var app = builder.Build();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

As you notice I do have the `.AddAuthorization` method above but when run and opening a browser localhost is not running.

I'm probably missing something very obvious here, have spent some hours searching here without any luck.

Comment: I think the [middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order) is no correct. Have tried to drag the `app.UseAuthorization();` middleware below? Would you kindly [`check the middlware order here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when this is run from a "docker-compose up" I dot get specific
> error.

According to your shared code snippet, you [are having the right exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0001?view=aspnetcore-8.0). Though, you have added the `app.UseAuthorization()` however, the [middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order) has not been followed. Consequently, it has thrown that error.

In order to inject middleware order correctly, `app.UseAuthorization()` should be called after `app.UseRouting()` in middleware pipeline. [This is essential for the authorization middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order) to process requests after routes have been matched.

Correct order would be:

[image]

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Note:** Above order should resolve your error. In addition, [please refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order)

Comment: this solved the build issue, but still no swagger page is loading, not even a default empty page

Comment: Not sure about the swagger, I just tested the error you are getting and in by debugging I got this problem. For swagger, I would suggest you to post more specific description and reproducible sample so that also can be tested.

Comment: The wierd thing is that debugging did not show me any error, and what other files or code do you need ?

Comment: Well, here our concern were the middleware issue which has resolve, so it would be great, if there is new thread or question reagarding swagger, So for swagger, if it were I, first I would check if that works in local machine then I would check docker image then continue investigation. If there't no error you got please set the logger manually, because without specific description or error or anything its hard to help.

Comment: But based on your condition swagger only should work in Dev `if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()`. If you would like to open in Prod, please remove this `if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()`, or also set condition for other environment.

Comment: in my docker-compose I have this ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development, will continue trying other things

Comment: Yeah sure, try other environment like `IsProduction` or `IsStaging` which fits with your requirement.

Comment: Actually there were a couple of things that needed bo be changed including this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76175410/1461862 - appending the "swagger" to the URL ;-)

Comment: thanks for your help, check my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78242215/1461862

Comment: That's great and glad to know.

Answer (score 1):

So not only the order of the middleware was incorrect but there were a couple of things missing in the swagger configuration

the RoutePrefix is set to empty so that opening localhost:5000/ will show the swagger page, otherwise localhost:5000/swagger should be used

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace WebApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            var services = builder.Services;

            // Add DbContext
            services.AddDbContext<ParkingDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            // Add Swagger services
            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });

            // Add controllers
            services.AddControllers();

            var app = builder.Build();

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // Enable Swagger UI
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
                    c.RoutePrefix = "";
                });
            }

            // Enable endpoint routing
            app.UseRouting();

            // Configure authentication and authorization
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            // Map controllers
            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```